# jQuery .removeClass() not working

Tags: jquery, css

I need to remove a CSS class from an text field since I want to change its background color. I need to change the color back later, so I have to add and remove classes to the field, depending on some data.

`.addClass` is working totally fine. The problem is that the original class is above the added, so the changes are not shown, but the class is added properly. I now try to remove the class which is above the added - but I cant remove any classes from my elements. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
if(i.stadt=="T") {
    $("#stadtInput").removeClass("ui-input-text input");
    $("#stadtInput").removeClass("ui-input-search input");
    $("#stadtInput").addClass( 'textboxRight' );
} else {
    $("#stadtInput").addClass( 'textboxWrong' );
}
```

If I inspect the elements with Webdev-Tools of browser I can see that the `textboxRight`/`textboxWrong` class is added, but no class is removed. I already tried to remove all classes by `.removeClass()`, but that doesn't work either..

Comment: Code looks fine, when does this code run? doc ready? window load?

Comment: are you sure i.stadt=="T" is returning true? can we see the HTML?

Comment: Could you put this in a fiddle or something? The code looks fine so I want to see how it's used in context..

Comment: Also you can put your first block of code in the if statement like this to make it shorter: $("#stadtInput").removeClass("ui-input-text ui-input-search input").addClass("textboxRight");

Comment: The removeClass/addClass part is fine, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Thvh4/ . So the problem is somewhere else, if you can share some HTML and more JS (for example, just to check what is the variable `i` etc...)

Comment: I had similiar problem but had named my div id with the name of hidden form field.  It was applying the addClass/removeClass to the hidden form field instead of the div.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fit your specifications, but the jQuery attr() method will take two arguments and replace all of the classes with the class name your provide. This won't work if you have other classes that you want to keep on your element, but if not try:

```
    $("#stadtInput").attr("class", "textboxRight");
```

Comment: This sure helped in my case! I was working with jquery.flexslider and inside the callbacks given for this plugIn the removeClass() won’t work. For me this is a live saver. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The next few lines works for me

```
var current = $(el).closest(".panel").find(".panel-collapse");
    if( $(current).hasClass("in") ) {
        setTimeout(function(){///workaround
            $(".panel-collapse").removeClass("in");
        }, 10);
    } else {
        $(current).addClass("in");
    }
```

Comment: Similarly, 

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $keys.removeClass("st-disabled");
  }, 10);

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. It turned out jQuery was returning an array with just one item. Follow me here:

```
var jqueryObject = $("#prefix-" + itemNum); <-- this gave me an array of 1.
```

Instead of

```
jqueryObject.removeClass("some-class");
```

I needed

```
jqueryObject[0].removeClass("some-class");
```

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem earlier on. Am no expert in jquery yet so I don't know if it behaves like css' specificity. My fix was to remove the class by using higher specificity. e.g
Instead of using `$(this).removeClass('acb')`, try using higher specificity like `$('#div1').children().first()`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when working on a rails app with the `HAML` templating gem as I included the `#` at the very beginning and it is not really needed. When I removed it, it started working.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume an array of elements:

```
var someElements = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass');
```

Didn't work: `someElements[1].removeClass('.someClassToRemove');`

**Worked:** `$(someElements[1]).removeClass('.someClassToRemove');`

So, maybe your issue was related with the object being an array or any incompatible type.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I soon discovered that it just didn't work for an `svg` element, so that gave me the clue to update my jQuery version (used 1.8.2). That solved the problem.